Why am I getting "Image palette is too big or absent" error with my TTrayIcon?
I'm developing a desktop application and I'm trying to use a TTrayIcon to display an icon in the system tray. However, I keep getting the error message:

Image palette is too big or absent

What could be causing this issue?

The icon I was using had a 1-bit black and white color palette. TTrayIcons often require icons with a more standard color depth, such as 8-bit or 24-bit.
To fix this, I converted the icon to use a higher color depth in a software like GreenFish Icon Editor Pro, and the error was resolved.

That's the very point: 1-bit is neither a palette, nor needs it one. You added one that wasn't there to begin with (see format). Hence the correct error message.

I created the icon using the Greenfish Icon Editor. When we try to create an icon from an image, there is a 1-bit option. Even in your link, the monochrome option appears (should be 0 in offset?). I believe this is what the software does. Could you please explain your point better? I think I missed something.

"ICONDIRENTRY structure: Offset# 2, Size 1: Specifies number of colors in the color palette. Should be 0 if the image does not use a color palette." - that means a color palette in an icon is optional. Which means your initial icon didn't have one, as otherwise the error message wouldn't apply for that issue ("absent").
